# Cant figure out parent().prev() combo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parent-child

I have the following code and script. With reference to the inner input, id="sfctry", my jquery is having trouble getting the outer input, id="eca".

As you can see in the script tag, I currently have $(this).parents('ul').prev().find('input.cccc'), but I have also tried closest(), prev().prev().prev(), and other combinations.

Thanks for your help.

```
    <li id="sepe">
        <input type="checkbox" id="eca" name="eca" class="cccc">
        <label for="eca" ><?php echo $this->translate('Shall'); ?></label><br>
        <a id="ep" title="Select">Select</a>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($this->data['ectries'] as $e-cp_r) {
                if ($this->form_data['sfctry'] == $e-cp_r['cp_id']) {
                    unset($e-cp_r);
                            } else {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <input <?php echo in_array($e-cp_r['cp_id'], $ids) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> type="checkbox" id="sfctry" name="item_s"  value="<?php echo $e-cp_r['cp_id']; ?>"><label for="sfctry"><?php echo $e-cp_r['tribe']; ?></label>
                    </li>
                <?php
                }
                        } ?>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <script>
       if ($('input[name="item_s"]').not(':checked').length === 0){
        $(this).parents('ul').prev().find('input.cccc').prop({
            indeterminate: false,
            checked: true
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is $(this) defined?

Comment: `prev()` just gets the immediate previous element. To get any previous sibling use `prevAll` - see https://api.jquery.com/prevall. A more flexible way might be something like `$(this).parents('ul').parents('li').find('input.cccc');`.

Comment: obviously $(this) is not referring to your checkbox in code. also if you have multiple checkboxes try to use class instead of id. you need to bind event e.g. on click etc.

Comment: i guess you want to loop each li->Id"sepe" and if none of checkbox is checked you want to set properties for input cccc. is this what you are trying?

Comment: Tx everyone. Yes, @Farhan, that is what I am trying to do, but I am having trouble cuz as git-e-up rightly pointed out, $(this) is not defined.

Comment: @git-e-up, No, it turns out $(this) is not defined? I'm struggling with how to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I reckon you'd want to replace `$(this)` with `$('input[name="item_s"]')` or just `$('#sfctry')` but you'll probably need to play around with the .parents().prev() stuff. Maybe try `$('#sfctry').parents('#sepe').find('input.cccc').prop({etc...`

Comment: Tx @git-e-up. I wanted to use $(this) b/c there are several iterations of this code structure and I was hoping to write one js block that worked for each of them, while not affecting all of them....

Comment: Well you should probably tie it into an event, like some kind of click or submit on a specific element and then work your way back to $(this). Sorry if that's a broad answer, but I don't think I have enough to be more specific. Also, as you probably know, you should not reuse the same id on a page.

Comment: Tx @git-e-up: It is actually wrapped into a listener on page load: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {. So, I can't tie it to an event. I've got it working for each iteration separately with reference to the names and classes, but I was looking for a more efficient function. Appreciate the ideas.

Comment: So can you just wrap it in a $('input[name="item_s"]').each() function? Then $(this) should work in some fashion.